# Programmatically Get Height of Collection View Section Outside Collection View Protocol Methods

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a chat app and the chat collectionView is created in a pod file that I don't have access to change. Each chat message is a section in the collectionView. I can determine the number of sections (chat messages) by calling myCollectionView.numberOfSections.

I want to determine the height of each section in the collectionView. How might I do this programmatically without using the collectionView protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
class ThirdPartyViewController: UIViewController  {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

}

class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let vc = ThirdPartyViewController()
    var collectionView: UICollectionView { return vc.collectionView }
    var originDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { return vc as! UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        //return custom value
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        //return origin value
        return originDelegate.collectionView!(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```